# separate two dates using space

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dataframe, datetime

I have two dates in a row and I want to split them using space.
Difficulty here is the date format keeps changing.

Samples :

```
good one : "01/27/19 09/31/18"
sample1 : "1/19/2011/19/19", expected "01/19/20 11/19/19"
sample2: "01/12/1812/15/1", expected "01/12/18 12/15/1"
```

I was trying out something like this :

code :

```
a['Text'] = a['Text'][0:8] + " " + a['Text'][-8:]
```

output for above code :

```
sample 1: "1/19/201 11/19/19"
 sample 2: "01/12/1 812/15/1"
```

Comment: If the format keeps changing then it's little difficult to convert to the datetime object

Comment: What does your current attempt output?

Comment: @bigbounty - we dont have to convert to datetime object, just get it in a proper shape.

Comment: @BruceWayne , hey I have updated the question, can you check th output for sample 1 and 2 in there

Comment: @here, can we split the date after two slashes two numbers ?

Comment: @BruceWayne  can you check my answer and give some suggestions ?

Comment: @bigbounty can you check my answer and give some suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a real ugly way to solve it:

```
>>> sample1 = "1/19/2011/19/19"
>>> sample2 = "01/12/1812/15/1"
>>> samples = [sample1, sample2]
>>> for sample in samples:
...   " ".join(["{:0>2}/{:0>2}/{:0>2}".format(*i) for i in re.findall(r"(?:(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2}))", sample)])
...
'01/19/20 11/19/19'
'01/12/18 12/15/01'
```

Using regular-expression we extract all of the numbers inside of the date, and then we use string-formatting to automatically add a 0 to the beginning if the found string is less than 2 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some way to concretely determine what date formats are possible? This seems a bit of a tricky case without a concrete way to know all of them.

If it's always a 2 slash format like shown above, where the first part is always 2 digits thought, you can do this in two parts. You can read the suffix by looking "back" 2 slashes, and then going 2 digits back.

It might be a bit of data juggling for a moment, but that seems like the reliable way if my assumptions about the data are right.

Then the first date is simply whatever string text remains.

To that end there's actually probably a regex capture group solution.

Comment: mostly of the three dates that I produced in the question. I can ignore the rest

Answer (score 1):

From your code I can infer that `a` is a `pandas.DataFrame` with a column named `Text`. In order to add two more columns to `a` containing the first and second date stored in `Text`, we can use some regex to split the dates in the midst of the middle 4-digit number that seems to be always present.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

a = pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['1/19/2011/19/19', '01/12/1812/15/1']})

a['first_date'] = a['Text'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('(\d+\/\d+\/\d{2})', x)[0])
a['second_date'] = a['Text'].str.replace('(\d+\/\d+\/\d{2})', '', n=1)

#               Text first_date second_date
# 0  1/19/2011/19/19    1/19/20    11/19/19
# 1  01/12/1812/15/1   01/12/18     12/15/1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(date) >=16:
    do regular date split
elif len(date) ==15:
    date_list = date.split('/')
    
    n = date_list[0] + '/' + date_list[1] + '/' + date_list[2][0:2] + ' ' + date_list[2][-2:] + '/' +  date_list[3] + '/' + date_list[4]
```

Please post if anyone has a better solution than this.

Comment: First do a format test using regex so that you are not receiving any garbage data. Then you can go ahead with your logic